# rows/columns not working with skeleton css

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to get three sections (each 1/3 length) on my page using skeleton.css. The website for the framework is [skeleton](http://getskeleton.com). This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
  <style type="text/css" href="css/skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="three columns">
        1
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="three columns">
        2
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="three columns">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that you want your columns in 3rds, use the `one-third` class instead and fix the second class to where it's just `column` vs. `columns`. You should also remove the two additional `row` containers and put them all in one:

```css
.example-grid .column {
  background: #EEE;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
  <style type="text/css" href="css/skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container example-grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="one-third column">
        1
      </div>

      <div class="one-third column">
        2
      </div>

      <div class="one-third column">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```